# When I install eric6, I get the following error:Please install QScintilla2 and its PyQt5/PyQt4 wrapper

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qscintilla

When I installed eric6, I was prompted with the following problems:

```
Python Version: 3.6.5
Found PyQt5
Found pyuic5
Sorry, please install QScintilla2 and its PyQt5/PyQt4 wrapper.
Error: DLL load failed: Cannot find the specified program!
```

But I have installed QScintilla via "pip install QScintilla", so what should I do next?

My operating system is Windows.

Comment: @eyllanesc Thank You for your edit.

Answer (score 0):

I see this error on today too , I used pip to install this module but all stop or fail, so I just can download 'whl' from pypi.org and 'pip install *.whl'. and re-install sip and PyQt5<5.9.3> before. And fixed. you can try it.

Answer (score 0):

sip-4.19.4-cp36-none-win_amd64
PyQt5-5.9.2-5.9.3-cp35.cp36.cp37-none-win_amd64
QScintilla-2.10.1-5.9.1-cp35.cp36.cp37-none-win_amd64

install sequence: sip -> PyQt5 - QScintilla